# How to get the number of items / rows / length / count of gtk.ListStore

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

Consider this example:

```
import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk

initarr = [ "aa", "bb", "xx" ]

liststore1 = gtk.ListStore(str)
for item in initarr:
  liststore1.append([item])

# one more:
liststore1.append(["whatever"])

# how to get length/size of liststore1 at this point?
```

As the comment says - how do I get the length / size of `liststore1` at end of this code?

Comment: `print len(liststore1)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just simply `print len(liststore1)`

To count particular items in a list:

```
l = ["foo","foo","bar"]
print l.count("foo")
2
```